# Pluralize method - How to get pluralized word to appear before the number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if it is possible to pluralize a word and have it appear before the number that is determining the pluralization instead of after it. Thanks!

Example:

```
<%= link_to pluralize(@user.posts.length, "Post "), posts_path(@post)  %>
```

It outputs "1 Post "

and id like it to output
"Post 1"
"Posts 2"

Comment: Do you really want to output "Post: 1"? That seems a little odd grammar wise, but maybe just me.

Comment: haha whoops fixed grammer now. Still want the number to appear after the text though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String` class has a `pluralize` method as well, to which you can pass the count:

```
"#{"Post".pluralize(@user.posts.length)} #{@user.posts.length}"
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!